# Maximizing by swapping

Tags: code-golf

## Input

An integer n in the range 100 to 10^18 and an integer k in the range 1 to 18, inclusive.

## The swap operation

A swap chooses two digits at different positions and exchanges their positions, as long as the swap does not result in a leading zero. For example if we start with the integer `12345` we can perform one swap to make it `12543`.

## Task

Output the largest number you can get after exactly k swaps.

## Examples

```
n = 1283, k = 2. Output: 8312
n = 510, k = 1. Output: 501
n = 501, k = 2. Output: 501
n = 999, k = 3. Output: 999
n = 12345678987654321, k = 1. Output: 92345678187654321
```

Comment: What is it with these `[code-golf]` + `[restricted-time]` challenges lately.. They are complete opposites imho. Anyway, as for the actual challenge, if we are to output huge test cases with `k=18` and `n` between \$10^{17}\$ and \$10^{18}\$ within 10 seconds, you may want to add some test cases for those.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen It's a combination I really like :) Basically the challenge is to write compact code that is not too naive/brute force.  I will try to add some more test cases.If anyone comes up with any first, please post them in the comments and I will add them to the question.

Comment: Also, a test case where `k` is larger than the length of `n` would be good as well, since we have to do exactly `k` swaps instead of up to `k` swaps. Can't really think of a good test case for this, but I think we might need to do an inefficient swap first sometimes in order to get to the maximum in exactly `k` swaps.

Comment: May we take `n` as a string?

Comment: @attinat Yes you can.

Comment: What should we do with `n=200`, `k=1`?

Comment: @H.PWiz I guess we should swap the zeros. An invalid input (IMO) would be `n=20`, `k=1`.

Comment: @Arnauld I was about to ask why `n=20`, `k=1` is invalid, but I now see the "_as long as the swap does not result in a leading zero_". And here I thought I was close to a solution.. xD You know, this would actually be a pretty good challenge I would upvote since we have to exactly `k` swaps (which is quite a bit harder than up to `k` swaps), if it weren't for the time-restriction. PS: I'm not one of the downvotes btw despite my first two comments, but I'm also not upvoting either.

Comment: Can we take input `n` as a list of digits?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yes you can.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I don't mind removing the time restriction if it makes people generally happier.

Comment: @Arnauld Your suggested input is invalid because it doesn't satisfy `n>=100`

Comment: I succumbed to peer pressure and removed [tag:restricted-time]

Comment: So this is basically the first k iterations of a sorting algorithm?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Not necessary, since `n=501, k=2` would become `510` in the first iteration, but then should be swapped back to `501` as our result.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I feel like that should've been explained better in the question, instead of by you on a comment ._. It confused both me and ovs.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Well, that's the difference between up to `k` swaps (which is pretty easy) and exactly `k` swaps (which is pretty tricky and is what this challenge is asking).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen They aren't off topic, right? https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133618/extreme-fibonacci

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>194</s> <s>190</s> <s>196</s> <s>193</s> <s>175</s> <s>164</s> 162 bytes

```python
def f(n,k):
 for i in range(len(n)-1):
  y=max(n[i:]);j=n[::-1].index(y)
  if(y>n[i])*k:n[i],n[~j]=y,n[i];k-=1
 if len(n)-len({*n})<k%2:n[-2:]=n[:-3:-1]
 return n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5BTsMwEEX3PsVsUO3IqbBdt4lLuEjkRVDi1Ek7qUyQGiG4erARSIXV1/vz9DXXZT5NqNa17Rw4inxkhoCbAnjwCKHBvqPnDimyXKQTLNWluVGsvbHsOFRYG5MLu/XYdje6sGh4R5fnKFiWjSYlx/pzsNXCExzHvBIkSvAzm@I9ww/2ND7I6OfS2DSbqzRMIHTzW0DAta/OzeWlbSB@aTab7TB5pI7W2esc4pCNvzNCrsHjTHsqZKG4jM1vocUjF3dcliVXdyyk2un9oSiLw17vlBR/bV3@Y/0trF8)

Pretty tough to golf this challenge in a real world language - I like it :)

After golfing down to 190 bytes (and below..), I found some cases where the algorithm would not find the maximum possible value. Bugfixing forced me back up to <s>196</s> 193 bytes :/

... then I found some ways to better handle branching on `k` and went down below 180 :)

After the comment from Chas Brown, switching from integer to list I/O saved 28 bytes! (And more golfing another 2..)

Then, another bug: the algorithm incorrectly handles remaining swaps, if there are equal digits present. The fix cost 19 bytes.

#### Algorithm:

1. For each digit, starting from the leftmost one, swap it with the rightmost maximum digit, if that one is bigger. First line of the `for`-loop finds the maximum and its index. Second line does the swap.
2. If there are `k'` swaps left, swap two equal digits, or the two rightmost `k'` times. I.e. if  there are two equal digits present, or if `k'` is even, no more swaps have to be done. Else, just swap the last two digits once.

Comment: The bug I needed to fix: f(899,1)=989, but should be 998. If there are multiple candidates to swap, use the rightmost one for the biggest effect. This is now taken care of by looking for the index in reverse. Takes up a lot of bytes for index calculation though :/

Comment: Hi and welcome, movatica! For the input `9881,1` you return `9818`; but you should return `9881`. (Also, you can take `n` as a string of digits already, and return a list of digits as well; as noted in the comments; so that should give you some breathing space! :)).

Comment: Hi @ChasBrown and thanx for the warm welcome :) You're right about the bug, this is because of how i handle possible swaps... I'm thinking of a way around. The removal of string/list handling will indeed save a lot of bytes.

Comment: [162 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY5BTsMwEEX3PsVsUO3IqbBdt4lLuEjkRVDi1Ek7qUyQGiG4erARSIXV1/vz9DXXZT5NqNa17Rw4inxkhoCbAnjwCKHBvqPnDimyXKQTLNWluVGsvbHsOFRYG5MLu/XYdje6sGh4R5fnKFiWjSYlx/pzsNXCExzHvBIkSvAzm@I9ww/2ND7I6OfS2DSbqzRMIHTzW0DAta/OzeWlbSB@aTab7TB5pI7W2esc4pCNvzNCrsHjTHsqZKG4jM1vocUjF3dcliVXdyyk2un9oSiLw17vlBR/bV3@Y/0trF8) by tweaking that last `if` clause a bit: `len(n)-len({*n})` must be `0` and `k%2` must be `1`, which is the condition `len(n)-len({*n})<k%2`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
JŒ!nJ$S⁼ɗƇ2ị⁸Ṁµ¡
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATAAz/9qZWxsef//SsWSIW5KJFPigbzJl8aHMuG7i@KBuOG5gMK1wqH///8xLDIsOCwz/zI)**

A dyadic Link accepting a list of digits (as non-negative integers) on the left and a non-negative integer on the right which yields a list of digits.

#### How?

```
JŒ!nJ$S⁼ɗƇ2ị⁸Ṁµ¡ - Link: L, n
              µ¡ - repeat the monad to the left n times -- i.e. f(f(f(...(L)...))):
J                -   range of length
 Œ!              -   all permutations
         Ƈ       -   filter keep if:
        ɗ 2      -     last three links as a dyad with right argument 2
     $           -       last two links as a monad:
    J            -         range of length
   n             -         not equal? (vectorises)
      S          -       sum
       ⁼         -       equal?
           ị     -   index into (vectorises):
            ⁸    -     chain's left argument, L
             Ṁ   -   maximum
```

---

**20 byte version** which is fine within the previous time-constraint since \$\binom{18}2=\frac{18\times 17}2=153\$

```
JŒcœṖḢ;Ḣ€ṚżƊƊFɗ€⁸Ṁµ¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/r6KTko5Mf7pz2cMciayB@1LTm4c5ZR/cc6zrW5XZyOpD7qHHHw50Nh7YeWvj//39DHSMdYx0THVMdMx1zHQsdSyA2B7JNgWLGQDnD/4YWAA)

#### How?

```
JŒcœṖḢ;Ḣ€ṚżƊƊFɗ€⁸Ṁµ¡ - Link: L, n
                  µ¡ - repeat the monad to the left n times -- i.e. f(f(f(...(L)...))):
J                    -   range of length
 Œc                  -   all (length(L)-choose-2) pairs: [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],...,[2,3],[2,4],...]
               €     -   for each (such pair, P):
              ɗ ⁸    -     last three links as a dyad, with right argument L:
   œṖ                -       partition (L) at indexes (P) - call this X
            Ɗ        -       last three links as a monad - i.e. f(X):
     Ḣ               -         head (of X) (the items up to but not including the first to swap)
           Ɗ         -         last three links as a monad - i.e. f(X):
       Ḣ€            -           head each (actually removes them too) (the items to swap)
         Ṛ           -           reverse
          ż          -           zip with (the altered X)
      ;              -         concatenate
             F       -       flatten
                 Ṁ   -   maximum
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>185</s> <s>177</s> <s>173</s> <s>166</s> <s>164</s> <s>161</s> 152 bytes

```python
def f(a,k):exec"i=0;j=L=len(a)-1\nwhile i<L>0<a[i]==max(a[i:]):i+=1\nwhile a[j]<max(a[i:]):j-=1\nj-=i==j<=L<len(set(a));a[i],a[j]=a[j],a[i];"*k;return a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/dcsIgEIXv8xQ79kJoMRMSo/nbXnrlG1hnpA2pREMyhE7t06eg1unN8rGHPXsYfuyx1/E01bKBhgh2ooW8yI@ZwqhscYtnqYmgC/6mv4/qLEFV29eoEju1R@zEhTgq9rRQL/h4InbtvvqntQuvuaoQ2wq3lfccpXW@tPROzE@gL8xfy9nzqTTSfhkNYnqCpjedsP4AKUYlDRgpaqU/wzAMNngW3XstQLMT8mI@D9teadKJgYzWsOZKSlt20AfqfkdpEFg52hEQCI@zJOOMU3ZjBvENI8eJxzz701MeMbj18vxB/E48Tpbpap3l2XqVLpPY9e@uDFK30od3CUFpuG4vAoDBuFywIa5Pg@kX)

Takes a list of digits and an integer k; returns a list of digits.

```python
j-=i==j<=L<len(set(a))
```

uses a bunch of shortcuts, and is the same as:

```python
if i==j:                     # if i==j, then the list is already sorted
    if len(a)-1<len(set(a)): # since len(a)>=len(set(a)) is *always* True,
                             # this means len(a)==len(set(a), i.e, 
                             # a has no duplicated digits,
        j = i-1              # so do a swap with the rightmost digits
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 113 bytes

```python
f=lambda l,k,E=enumerate:l*0**k or f(max(l[:i]+[y]+l[i+1:j]+[x]+l[j+1:]for(i,x)in E(l)for j,y in E(l)if i<j),k-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9BboMwEEX3nGKkLmKHKcIQEkBlmVwCIcVVTGowBhlXgtNTE0hXfv@PNPM8zPan19Gy1IXi3feDg8IWr4XQv50w3IpcHcPjsYXeQE06PhFV5rLyy7nyVSl9ljcuTGtoXKjq3hCJE5UarkRRF6HBGfYoa5BfDcX2k9HlA9y043Z9QPBRCgNG8IfUzyAIvNtbSGNbsPxwCJpeaqcwkNEarF8ktcW7vruNlFLPs2K0IxRAWJTGKUNGcWOEaMPQcbxilr7nCQsRti7L/ontxKL4lJwvaZZezskpjly/b0VI3MlV3hmuP3xdzz2AwTgvuBHXU2/5Aw)

Greedily does the best swap at each step, found by testing all possible swaps and taking the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 162 bytes

```powershell
$f={param($s,$k)if($k--){$s=if($s.length-le2){&$f($s[1]+$s[0])$k}else{($m=($s|% t*y|sort)[-1])+(&$f(($s-replace"(?<!$m.*)$m",$s[0])|% s*g 1)($k+=$s[0]-eq$m))}}$s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDhboJAEIT/@xRXspZbPYwHotCUtO9hSGPsqg1HpRxN2yDPThfQWu/HZe@bnblkiuMXlfZAxrQt7JK62JSbXIJVkOHbTkLmeViDTbrZzgy976uDZ8jH@h46tNbplO95ipA1ZCzVEvKEhdNYVJOfkz2WFa49neJUdg5WvJIKs9mSI58e7yCfTRByRw0h7LKTvdDIP0@Tnnn0ATli04Bt2mc5EnyUdLUfBa4SvhJuFGjfxYsQ6jlzzTyc63@YH8P6DY7jmHHAuJvwmh4swuUqiqPVMlwEvj5Hxmeu//jV4iqt3FvgDwDFSYxF3Qt9tQrou6BtRa8iEfAyCCXZT1Mx4J54TUDWcwfkWeqauPjw4WJwRk37Cw)

The Recursive Function. Less golfed:

```powershell
$f={
    param($s,$k)
    if($k--){
        $s=if($s.length-le2){
            &$f ($s[1]+$s[0]) $k
        }
        else{
            $max=($s|% t*y|sort)[-1]
            $k+=$s[0]-eq$max
            $s=$s-replace"(?<!$max.*)$max",$s[0]
            $s=$s|% subString 1
            $max+(&$f $s $k)
        }
    }
    $s
}
```

---

### Alternative, 169 bytes

```powershell
param($s,$k)1..$k|%{do{if($s.length-le2){$s=-join$s[1,0]
$r=0}else{$m+=($c=($s|% t*y|sort)[-1])
$r=$s[0]-eq$c
$s=($s-replace"(?<!$c.*)$c",$s[0])|% s*g 1}}while($r)}$m+$s
```